# Best return type policy in python

Tags: python, exception, error-handling

I looking for a "the way its meant to be done" solution for the next problem:

I have a class called `InputChecker`, which takes an input file, checks the content of it, and if all is well, returns the file to next class (`ExpofitAgent`) for further actions.

However, if the file is not in the form as it should be, `InputChecker` generates an error message which says on which line of the file the error was found.

`InputChecker` doesn't print the error, it just generates the message which is printed later.

Since I'm doing it in python my method can return a file or a string. How to do a check if the file is ok without the need of including an additional flag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm having a hard time thinking of a situation where [Marcin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9979758/5987) of using an exception wouldn't be the best answer.

However if you do need an alternative, it's easy to return more than one thing at a time in Python using a tuple.

```
def myfunc():
    # ...
    if file_is_ok:
        return myfile, None
    else:
        return None, error_string

mf, es = myfunc()
if es:
    # show error string
```

Answer (score 21):

Raise an exception: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html

> Even if a statement or expression is syntactically correct, it may cause an error when an attempt is made to execute it. Errors detected during execution are called *exceptions* and are not unconditionally fatal... Most exceptions are not handled by programs, however, and result in error messages...

Comment: Seems like i didn't post the question well enough. The error message is generated by me, and is just a string variable in a form etc. "There is an error on line 6 of your file".

So it's not a situation in which I would want to rise an exception (given that in Python the philosophy is that catching exceptions should be used just for errors that couldn't be handled differently)

Comment: @Alan Go ahead and use that string as the argument to an exception. Even better if you create your own exception, and give it appropriate metadata about the location of the error, so it can be processed programmatically.

Comment: @Alan It is also not the case that the recommended python practice is to avoid exceptions.

Comment: @Alan, I think you misunderstand Python's philosophy with exceptions. They're meant to be used more often than in C++ for example. Yes you should only catch an exception if you know what to do with it, but exceptions are *more* flexible in that they give you the choice of where to handle it or if you just want the program to stop.

Comment: @Alan: Mark & Marcin are right. The exceptions in Python aren't so specific (`TypeError`, `ValueError`, `KeyError`, `IOError`, `DecodeError`, `ImportError`, Django's `{SomeModelClass}.DoesNotExist` etc.) without purpose. They are the better approach, make your code simpler, cleaner, shorter, more robust (eg. for multiple threads where everything may happen between checking some file for correctness and actually using it). Just use your own exception inheriting from the exception class that is the closest to what you want to achieve.